# Pull and Run a Docker container using Azure Runbook

Tags: azure, docker, azure-runbook

I want to create a **Runbook** to automate the execution of a **Docker container** in Azure.
I'v used **PowerShell Runbook** and here is my code:

```
    # Install Azure CLI
Invoke-Expression -Command "Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://aka.ms/installazurecliwindows -OutFile installazurecli.ps1"
.\installazurecli.ps1
# Log in to Azure using the Azure CLI
az login --service-principal --username $appId --password $password --tenant $tenantId

# Set the ACR details
$acrName = "test"
$acrResourceGroup = "test"
$acrUsername = "test"
$acrPassword = "000000000000000000000000000000000000"
$aciName = "test"
$imageName = "test.azurecr.io/test:test"
$aciPort = 80

# Pull the Docker image from Azure Container Registry
az acr login --name $acrName
az acr repository login --name $acrName
docker pull $imageName

# Run the Docker container in Azure Container Instances
az container create --name $aciName --resource-group $aciResourceGroup --image $imageName --ports $aciPort --registry-login-server $acrName

# Get the container status
az container show --name $aciName --resource-group $aciResourceGroup --query 'instanceView.currentState.state'
```

This code just generate the status code here:

```
ActivityId        : 174593042
ParentActivityId  : -1
Activity          : Web request status
StatusDescription : Number of bytes processed: 7176192
CurrentOperation  : 
PercentComplete   : -1
SecondsRemaining  : -1
RecordType        : Processing
```

But it doesn't semes to send any requests to my Docker registry.

Comment: There's a few things awry in your code.

You don't need to do any of the 3 lines where you do a docker pull
You're using the ACRName instead of the ACR Login Server $acrLoginServer = az acr show -g $acrResourceGroup -n $acrName --query loginServer -o tsv
You're not providing credentials to access the registry

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @

[GordonBy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/66112/gordonby). As he says, you have to provide ACR registry credentials to `az container create command` while deploying the image from ACR to ACI.  Below is the full command to create a container instance.

```
# Run the Docker container in Azure Container Instances
az container create --name $aciName --resource-group $ResourceGroup --image $imageName --ports $aciPort --registry-login-server $registryLoginServer --registry-username $acrUsername --registry-password $acrPassword
```

To get the container status, use the query `instanceView.state` as below.

```
# Get the container status
az container show --name $aciName --resource-group $ResourceGroup --query 'instanceView.state'
```

Below is the full code.

```
# Log in to Azure using the Azure CLI
az login --service-principal --username $username --password $password --tenant $tanantId

$acrName = "acrvjy"
$ResourceGroup = <rg-name>
$acrUsername = "acrvjy"
$acrPassword = <acr-passwd>
$aciName = "killedacivjyhcgdc43"
$imageName = "acrvjy.azurecr.io/flaskimg:latest"
$aciPort = 8000
$registryLoginServer = "acrvjy.azurecr.io"

# Run the Docker container in Azure Container Instances
az container create --name $aciName --resource-group $ResourceGroup --image $imageName --ports $aciPort --registry-login-server $registryLoginServer --registry-username $acrUsername --registry-password $acrPassword

# Get the container status
az container show --name $aciName --resource-group $ResourceGroup --query 'instanceView.state'
```

**Output:**
[image]

To test the same in azure runbook, I have used azure powershell commands as `az` cli commands not available by default.

```
$SecurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString <Password> -AsPlainText -Force

$Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($applicationId, $SecurePassword)

Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Credential $Credential -Tenant $tenantId

  

$acrName = "acrvjy"

$ResourceGroup = <rg-name>

$acrUsername = "acrvjy"

$acrPassword = <acrpassword>

$aciName = "acitestig0124"

$imageName = "acrvjy.azurecr.io/flaskimg:latest"

$aciPort = 8000

$registryLoginServer = "acrvjy.azurecr.io"

  

$container = New-AzContainerInstanceObject -Name $aciName -Image $imageName

$imageRegistryCredential = New-AzContainerGroupImageRegistryCredentialObject -Server $registryLoginServer -Username $acrUsername -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString $acrPassword -AsPlainText -Force)

$containerGroup = New-AzContainerGroup -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup -Name $aciName -Location eastus -Container $container -ImageRegistryCredential $imageRegistryCredential

$aciStatus= (Get-AzContainerGroup -Name $aciName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup).InstanceView.State

$aciStatus
```

**Output:**
[image]

Comment: Thank you! I'm getting this now:
Line |
   3 |  … redential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($app …
     |                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Exception calling ".ctor" with "2" argument(s): "Cannot process argument
     | because the value of argument "userName" is not valid. Change the value
     | of the "userName" argument and run the operation again."